# 'AND columnName NOT IN' not working in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have build a query as it follows

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE postUserId IN (SELECT userB 
                     FROM friends 
                     WHERE userA = 1) 
   OR postUserId IN (SELECT userA 
                     FROM friends 
                     WHERE userB = 1) 
  AND postUserId NOT IN (2) 
ORDER BY postId DESC
```

the query results in all the rows showing i need to hide `WHERE NOT IN` but the results are not as expected

Comment: You need to group your conditions. `WHERE (.. OR ...) AND ..`

Comment: would you mind providing us the sample result set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add parenthesis properly for your desired result

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE ( postUserId IN (SELECT userB 
                     FROM friends 
                     WHERE userA = 1) 
   OR postUserId IN (SELECT userA 
                     FROM friends 
                     WHERE userB = 1) 
    )
  AND postUserId NOT IN (2) 
ORDER BY postId DESC
```